# Error message in labeling tick marks

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I want to label a tick mark on the x-axis and a tick mark on the y-axis.  I put a "%" before the commands in the following code so that the line could be plotted and the tick marks can be drawn.  The tick mark on the y-axis is 30,042; I understand that `TikZ` interprets this as two numbers.  I tried using $30,042$ and also got an error.  How do I get 30,042 on the y-axis and 60,084 on the x-axis?

```
\documentclass[10pt]{amsart}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.11}


\begin{document}


\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[width=5in,axis equal image,
    axis lines=middle,
    xmin=-5000,xmax=70000,samples=2,
    xlabel=$x$,ylabel=$y$,
    ymin=-5000,ymax=35000,
    restrict y to domain=-5000:35000,
    enlargelimits={abs=0.5cm},
    axis line style={latex-latex},
    ticklabel style={font=\tiny,fill=white},
    extra x ticks={60084},
%    extra x tick labels={60,084},
    extra y ticks={30,042},
%    extra y tick labels={$30,042$},
    yticklabel style={anchor=east},
    xtick={\empty},ytick={\empty},
    xlabel style={at={(ticklabel* cs:1)},anchor=north west},
    ylabel style={at={(ticklabel* cs:1)},anchor=south west}
]

\addplot[latex-latex,samples=200,domain=-5000:70000,blue] {-0.5*x + 30042} node[above, pos=0.75,font=\footnotesize]{$3x + 6y = 180,252$};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}


\end{document}
```

Comment: Unless I missed something, removing the comma from `extra y ticks={30,042},` results in a plot with the tick labels that you describe.

Comment: Use only `extra x ticks={60084},extra y ticks={30042}` and remove `extra y tick labels={$30042$},` and `extra x tick labels={60084}`

Comment: @Christopher  I want the label on the y-axis to be "30,042."

Comment: @Harish Kumar  I did exactly what you said by putting the "%" before the commands ` extra y tick labels={$30042$},` and `extra x tick labels={60084}`.  I want these labels on the axes as "30,042" and "60,084."

Comment: That is what you get: http://i.stack.imgur.com/rrcOA.png

Comment: @Harish Kumar  Now, I get that.  (I don't know what happened when I first compiled it with "%" before the commands for the extra tick labels.)  What code would give me the two tick marks on the axes without the labels?

Comment: @Adelyn That's what removing the comma does as Harish Kumar has elucidated further. To remove the labels simply add `extra x tick labels={\empty},` and the y-variant to the axis section.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As discussed in the comments, the problem here is the comma in the number 30,042. This needs to be changed to 30042. By default you will get the thousand separator comma that you desire. You do not need the `extra x tick labels` part to get the desired output.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{amsart}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[width=5in,axis equal image,
    axis lines=middle,
    xmin=-5000,xmax=70000,samples=2,
    xlabel=$x$,ylabel=$y$,
    ymin=-5000,ymax=35000,
    restrict y to domain=-5000:35000,
    enlargelimits={abs=0.5cm},
    axis line style={latex-latex},
    ticklabel style={font=\tiny,fill=white},
    extra x ticks={60084},
    extra y ticks={30042},
    yticklabel style={anchor=east},
    xtick={\empty},ytick={\empty},
    xlabel style={at={(ticklabel* cs:1)},anchor=north west},
    ylabel style={at={(ticklabel* cs:1)},anchor=south west}
]

\addplot[latex-latex,samples=200,domain=-5000:70000,blue] {-0.5*x + 30042} node[above, pos=0.75,font=\footnotesize]{$3x + 6y = 180,252$};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

As Harish Kumar already pointed out gives:

[image]

As you requested it in the comments to remove the labels but leave the ticks in place you can add, `extra x tick labels={\empty},` and `extra y tick labels={\empty},` into the axis section. Which gives:

[image]